# How do I provide security in the aspx file downloads?

Tags: asp.net, download, webforms, ftp

I have web form project, example my link is www.qweqwe.com/setup.exe
if i can write url "www.qweqwe.com/setup.exe" file is downloading automatically.

I don't want this, I need session for download this. I musn't change file name, when session["scr"] is "Ok" than i must let.

(I will use ClickOnce but i don't want can be download from everypeople)

Thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
//First check for Session Variable 
if(Session["scr"]!=null)
{
//Now if you want file only downloaded by only some specific person then

if(Session["scr"].ToString()=="You Specific Session value")
{
//Here Your File download code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a Generic Handler for downloading files (ASHX).

In the `ProcessRequest` method you can check the session and serve the file. Here is an example:

```
public class Download : IHttpHandler
{ 
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string file = "setup.exe";
        if (File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath(file)) && Session["scr"].ToString() == "Ok")
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(file));
            context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath(file));
            context.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("File cannot be found!");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the MIME for the exe file in your IIS so nobody can download it, directly.